# Grails/Groovy CRUD Service

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi I am a student and I am currently learning Grails and Groovy. I want to make Crud Service with a Service, Controller and a GSP. I connected my Grails application with a PostgreSQL database. My problem is I can't make the CRUD service. I did it with scaffold, then I try it manually in a controller and now I want to put it in a service. My code is this:

My service

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class ContactListService {
    def DataSource

    def listAction(){
        def sql = new Sql(DataSource)
        return sql.rows ("SELECT * FROM  mn")
    }

    def insertAction(){
        def sql = new Sql(DataSource)
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO  mn (id, name) VALUES ($Id,$Name)")
    }
```

I get this "Message: No such property: Id for class: contactlist.ContactListService"

Comment: Just for make you know, you dont need to create an sql connection in that way. Use GORM: Mn.list() = select * from mn, and new Mn(id: Id, name: name).save() = insert. Assuming that you have a class named Mn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, there's no bean named `DataService` (what for a weird naming btw). Instead there's a bean named `dataService`

2nd, To solve the compile error, you must declare the `Id` and `Name` (my eyes are bleeding now!) somewhere in the context of your `insertAction()` method. Either as arguments, or fields or local vars, like:

```
def insertAction( String Id, String Name ){ // aaarrrgggghhhh
    def sql = new Sql(DataSource)
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO  mn (id, name) VALUES ($Id,$Name)")
}
```

Comment: Using incorrect case like that accidentally works for dependency injection because the generated setter and getter are the same for `dataSource` and for `DataSource` (and the setter is what is used by Spring for DI). Best to do it the standard way though of course.

Comment: Thanx for answering. The update tag is working the same way?

Comment: @Andrew you mean `sql.execute( "update ..." )`? yes, it does. Though, if you want to stick with `groovy.sql`, use positional or named parameters for your queries: `sql.execute('INSERT INTO  mn (id, name) VALUES (?,?)', [ id, name ] )`

Comment: @injecteer   can you help me with the whole CRUD service and controller? I cant find anything like this i want

Comment: @BurtBeckwith can you help me with the whole CRUD service and controller? I cant find anything like this i want

Comment: @Andrew post your questions - this is the only way we can help you

Comment: @injecteer i put the service in the controller [contact: contactListService.insertAction(params.id,params.Name)] and i get the following error: No signature of method: contactlist.ContactListService.insertAction() is applicable for argument types: (null, java.lang.String) values: [null, das] Possible solutions: insertAction(int, java.lang.String), listAction()

Comment: @Andrew either update your original question or create new ones to avoid getting banned for brutal off-topic

Answer (score 1):

For starters I would avoid using SQL unless it is needed, for example if you need to use something that is non-standard that cannot be done with Hibernate and/or GORM. Simple insert and select statements like yours are trivial with the built-in features of Grails and GORM.

There are many resources available to learn the basics of Grails. See the [reference docs](https://grails.org/documentation.html) but also check out one or more of the [many books](https://grails.org/wiki/Books) that are available. There are no books specific to Grails 3 yet, but the core concepts in Grails 2 and 3 are very similar, so the Grails 2 books will help a lot.

The reason your code is failing is that you are referencing a non-existent `Id` variable in the GString with your SQL. Assuming you fix that, it will fail again because of the missing `Name` variable. You probably want to pass those in as method parameters from the controller and other classes that call your service, e.g.

```
def insertAction(long id, String name) {
    def sql = new Sql(DataSource)
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO  mn (id, name) VALUES ($id,$name)")
}
```

Note that you are very close to adding a SQL injection risk to your application by using SQL with embedded variables like this. You're lucky that groovy.sql.Sql understands GStrings and avoids the problem in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew, You do not have to write sql queries in such scenarios which can lead you to the SQL Injection risk in your Application. Rather you can utilize GORM features to make your work easier.

Assuming that you have a class named Mn like this:

```
class Mn{
  Long id
  String name
}
```

Now, you can write list and insert action in service like this:

```
@Transactional
class ContactListService {

def listAction(){
    return Mn.list()
}

def insertAction(id, name){
    def mn = new Mn(id: id, name: name)
    mn.save()
}
}
```